# How to embed a linear gauge in a Kendo grid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was just researching Kendo UI. I can see that you can embed charts in the grid, but I am unsure that there is any representation for a 2-way linear gauge in Kendo UI.

Something along the lines of:[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have amended the code from the below Answer and hope that it helps you find answer.     
http://jsbin.com/muboqo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always integrate different types of Chart inside a Kendo Grid. The way to do this is you need to add a databound function in the grid which create chart so for each row databound it will create specific chart. I have a somewhat similar example of this for you please see this [link](http://jsbin.com/qepez/1/edit?html,output)

I have also kept relevant code script over here below:

```
<script> var firstNames = ["Nancy", "Andrew", "Janet", "Margaret", "Steven", "Michael", "Robert", "Laura", "Anne", "Nige"],
lastNames = ["Davolio", "Fuller", "Leverling", "Peacock", "Buchanan", "Suyama", "King", "Callahan", "Dodsworth", "White"],
cities = ["Seattle", "Tacoma", "Kirkland", "Redmond", "London", "Philadelphia", "New York", "Seattle", "London", "Boston"],
titles = ["Accountant", "Vice President, Sales", "Sales Representative", "Technical Support", "Sales Manager", "Web Designer",
"Software Developer", "Inside Sales Coordinator", "Chief Techical Officer", "Chief Execute Officer"],
birthDates = [new Date("1948/12/08"), new Date("1952/02/19"), new Date("1963/08/30"), new Date("1937/09/19"), new Date("1955/03/04"), new Date("1963/07/02"), new Date("1960/05/29"), new Date("1958/01/09"), new Date("1966/01/27"), new Date("1966/03/27")];

function createRandomData(count) {
var data = [],
    now = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var firstName = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)],
        lastName = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)],
        city = cities[Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length)],
        title = titles[Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length)],
        birthDate = birthDates[Math.floor(Math.random() * birthDates.length)],
        age = now.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear(),
        tableValues = [];

  var projLength = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  for(var t=0;t<projLength;t++){
    tableValues.push({year:2005+t,value:Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)})
  }

    data.push({
        Id: i + 1,
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName,
        City: city,
        Title: title,
        BirthDate: birthDate,
        Age: age,
      tableValues:tableValues
    });
}
return data;
}</script>
            <div id="grid"></div>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: createRandomData(50),
                        pageSize: 10
                    },
                    groupable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: true
                    },
                  dataBound:function(){
                    var grid = this;
                    $(".chart").each(function(){
                      var chart = $(this);
                      var tr = chart.closest('tr');
                      var model = grid.dataItem(tr);
                      chart.kendoChart({ 
                      legend:{
                        visible:false
                      },
                        dataSource: {
                        data: model.tableValues
                    },
                    series: [{
                        field: "value",
                        name: "United States"
                    }],
                    valueAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            format: "{0}$"
                        }
                    },
                    categoryAxis: {
                        field: "year"
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{0}$"
                    }
                });
                    })
                  },
                    columns: [ {
                            field: "FirstName",
                            width: 90,
                            title: "First Name"
                        } , {
                            field: "LastName",
                            width: 90,
                            title: "Last Name"
                        } , {
                            width: 100,
                            field: "City"
                        } , {
                            field: "Title"
                        } , 
                        {
                          template:'<div class="chart" style="height:200px"></div>'   ,
                          width:350
                        },                                  
                              {
                            field: "BirthDate",
                            title: "Birth Date",
                            template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #'
                        } , {
                            width: 50,
                            field: "Age"
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Please let me know if you need any further help